# How do I invert windows colors using Compiz?

Tags: 14.04, compiz, colors

Does anyone know how to invert windows colors using Compiz, in ubuntu 14.04?
I installed Compiz Manager but the option is not visible.

[image: Compiz Manager not showing negative option]

Comment: Not sure about it, but did you try to install compiz-plugins package?

Comment: That's it, I was missing that package installation, thanks.

Comment: How does the invert plugin look like?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the compiz plugins packages.

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-main
```

an after this you'll get a plugin for negative color for window or screen.